# Problems understanding allocation system of cocos2d for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to learn cocos2d for iphone, following the following book http://www.apress.com/9781430233039. I modified the ShootEmUp3 example available in the CH_08 folder of the source code (http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/640/).

What I want to achieve is to have a menu scene and a game scene, and to be able to go back to the menu scene once the game scene is over (e.g. all lifes are lost). From the menu scene I can access a particular GameScene by clicking on icons which are istances of a class called "LevelIcon". In other words the menu scene, which I called "Navigator" (subclass of CCLayer), contains istances of the "LevelIcon" class (sublcass of NSObject) appearing in the menu scene and responding to the touch event by calling the replaceScene method of CCDirector, as following:.

```
//From LevelIcon.m    
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CCLOG(@"Touch");
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
    GameScene * game = [GameScene scene];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:game];
    return TRUE;
}
```

I tried to release the objects in the Navigator dealloc method but, adding a CCLOG message on the release method of LevelIcon I found out that the release method is never called.

```
//From Navigator.m

-(void)dealloc
{
    CCLOG(@"Navigator dealloc");
    CCLOG(@"%@: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self);

    level1 = nil;
    [level1 dealloc];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

I then added a log in the update method and observed that was still being called even if the scene was GameScene and not Navigator scene. The thing I cannot understand is that the LevelIcon was an object created in Navigator and in the dealloc method of Navigator I did attempts to release the istance of the class as shown above (**but does not do it**).

As confirmation of this I tried to go back and forwards from GameScene to Navigator in order to trigger the following piece of code in GameScene:

```
        Navigator * navigator = [Navigator scene];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:navigator];
```

And the creation of a new Navigator class works out properly but, when going back to GameScene the new LevelIcon class instance does not disappear but instead remains (so that it accumulates). We have to notice that the replaceScene method is called from within the LevelIcon class responding to a touch event as following:

```
GameScene * game = [GameScene scene];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:game];
```

In other words, after this event the Navigator release method is called and not the LevelIcon and if multiple times the LevelIcon class remains active in memory.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but would appreciete some hint or help.

I also tried a different approach, by adding the istance of LevelIcon as child of Navigator (using the addChild method), but it does not work because is derived from a NSObject class and not a cocos2d Node class. I was wondering if it makes sense to tweak this somehow or if it not meat to be as of the two different class hierarchy (cocos2d and NS/Objective-C).

I paste the complete code to help understand:

```
--NAVIGATOR.H-----

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "LevelIcon.h"

@interface Navigator : CCLayer {
    LevelIcon *level1;
}

+ (id) scene;

@end


-----NAVIGATOR.M------
#import "Navigator.h"
#import "LevelIcon.h"

@implementation Navigator

+(id) scene {
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    CCLayer *layer = [Navigator node];//??
    [scene addChild:layer];
    return scene;     
}

-(id)init 
{
    CCLOG(@"init");
    if((self=[super init])){        
        CCLOG(@"%@: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self);
        self.isAccelerometerEnabled=YES;
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

        [self scheduleUpdate];  
        level1 = [LevelIcon levelIconWithParentNode:self];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    CCLOG(@"Navigator dealloc");
    CCLOG(@"%@: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self);

    level1 = nil;
    [level1 dealloc];

    [super dealloc];
}
[..]
@end


------LEVELICON.H------------
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface LevelIcon : NSObject<CCTargetedTouchDelegate> {
    CCSprite* levelIconSprite;
 }

+(id) levelIconWithParentNode:(CCNode*)parentNode;
-(id) initWithParentNode:(CCNode*)parentNode;

@end



-----LEVEL ICON.M----------------
#import "LevelIcon.h"
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation LevelIcon

// Static autorelease initializer, mimics cocos2d's memory allocation scheme.
+(id) levelIconWithParentNode:(CCNode*)parentNode
{
    CCLOG(@"levelIconWithParentNode");  
    return [[[self alloc] initWithParentNode:parentNode] autorelease];
}

-(id) initWithParentNode:(CCNode*)parentNode 
{
    CCLOG(@"initWithParentNode");
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        CCLOG(@"initWithParentNode: inside if");
        CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        levelIconSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon.png"];
        levelIconSprite.position = CGPointMake(CCRANDOM_0_1() * screenSize.width, CCRANDOM_0_1() * screenSize.height);
        [parentNode addChild:levelIconSprite];

        // Manually schedule update via the undocumented CCScheduler class used internally by CCNode.
        [[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] scheduleUpdateForTarget:self priority:0 paused:NO];

        // Manually add this class as receiver of targeted touch events.
        [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:-1 swallowsTouches:YES];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    CCLOG(@"Level icon dealloc");
    // Must manually unschedule, it is not done automatically for us.
    [[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] unscheduleUpdateForTarget:self];

    // Must manually remove this class as touch input receiver!
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
    CCLOG(@"Icon Update!");
}


-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CCLOG(@"Touch");
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
    GameScene * game = [GameScene scene];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:game];
    return TRUE;
}

@end
```

Thanks for reading! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day I found out that the error was not directly caused by the calling of the release object.

The code above shows an autorelease initialization and hence there should be no need of calling the release. I agree, there was an error on my side by attempting to call release again in the Navigator. No excuses for this (the only one is my ignorance on this and having tried to do it without befoe with no success did lead me in trying to play around in the wrong way with the release without trusting the little known 'theory' and trying to find the problem in a more critical way).

The problem was that the object was "somehow" retained twice, and hence the dealloc was never being called.

To solve this I added the call to

```
[[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] unscheduleUpdateForTarget:self];
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
```

into the **ccTouchBegan** method, so that possible retains would have been lost.

In the definition of the method **removeDelegate** there is no explicit call to release but 
in **sharedDispatcher addTargetedDelegate** method there is a call to **ccArrayAppendObject** which retains the object passed as argument (see code below).

```
//From CCTouchDispatcher.m line 121
-(void) addTargetedDelegate:(id<CCTargetedTouchDelegate>) delegate priority:(int)priority swallowsTouches:(BOOL)swallowsTouches 
{
    CCTouchHandler *handler = [CCTargetedTouchHandler handlerWithDelegate:delegate priority:priority swallowsTouches:swallowsTouches];
    if( ! locked ) {
        [self forceAddHandler:handler array:targetedHandlers];
    } else {
        [handlersToAdd addObject:handler];
        toAdd = YES;
    }
}

//From ccCArray.h line 115 (after having opened the definition of several function starting from **addObject** being called by addTargetedDelegate I got here)
/** Appends an object. Bahaviour undefined if array doesn't have enough capacity. */
static inline void ccArrayAppendObject(ccArray *arr, id object)
{
    arr->arr[arr->num] = [object retain];
    arr->num++;
}
```

Then looking at the definition of **removeDelegate** (see code below) function now being called in **ccTouchBegan** I have observed that **sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate** adds the object to a list of **handlersToRemove** which are then released. This should be what causes the object to be released.

```
//From LevelIcon.m 
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CCLOG(@"Touch");
    [[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] unscheduleUpdateForTarget:self];
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];

    GameScene * game = [GameScene scene];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:game];



    return TRUE;
}

//From CCTouchDispatcher.m line 153
-(void) removeDelegate:(id) delegate
{
    if( delegate == nil )
        return;

    if( ! locked ) {
        [self forceRemoveDelegate:delegate];
    } else {
        [handlersToRemove addObject:delegate];
        toRemove = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty weird:

```
level1 = nil;
[level1 dealloc];
```

1) You don't want to call dealloc directly, use [level1 release] and when the reference count reaches 0 it will be automatically dealloc'ed

2) This order is wrong, after setting level1 to nil the next line has no effect (you can harmlessly send messages to nil pointers, they quietly do nothing).

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting. I modified the Navigator dealloc method removing the nil assignment and calling the release `[level1 release];`  the code now crashes as it attempts to call the LevelIcon release method twice `(2012-01-03 14:48:54.506 ShootEmUp[6120:207] Navigator dealloc
2012-01-03 14:48:54.507 ShootEmUp[6120:207] dealloc: <Navigator = 0545E850 | Tag = -1>
2012-01-03 14:48:54.507 ShootEmUp[6120:207] Level icon dealloc
2012-01-03 14:48:54.508 ShootEmUp[6120:207] Level icon dealloc)`

Comment: Also, I tried to remove `[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];` from the ccTouchBegan method in LevelIcon, thinking that it might have caused the double deallocation, but when doing so (hence leaving the call only in dealloc as shown in the code posted above it crashes..